# Capture links in scrapy using regex as selector

Tags: scrapy

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="&amp;ns_svg;" xmlns:xlink="&amp;ns_xlink;" width="700" height="700" viewBox="0 0 300 300" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
<a xlink:href="https://www.pros-locations-de-voitures.fr/location-de-voiture-ain-01/" onmouseover="TipFunction('Ain')" onmouseout="TipFunction('')"><path id="Z1" title="Ain" d="M237.125,152.725l-1.7-1l-2.4,3.3l-2.7,1.6l-2,0.1l-0.2-1.4l-1.6-0.8l-2,2.2l-1.5,0.1v-1.5h-1.5l-2.1-3.9 l-2.5-1.6l-2.7,0.6l-2.9-0.8l-2.9,10.5l-0.8,4l1.5,4.6l1.5-0.3l1.8,2.9l3.2-0.3l3,1l1.5-2.5l1.4-0.4l5.6,7.6l2.9-3.3l1.1-6.8    l-0.4-4.7h1.5l1.3-1.4h-0.1l0.3-2.6l2.8-1.7L237.125,152.725z" fill="red" stroke="#EEEEEE" stroke-width="0.9"></path> </a>
<a xlink:href="https://www.pros-locations-de-voitures.fr/location-de-voiture-aisne-02/" onmouseover="TipFunction('Aisne')" onmouseout="TipFunction('')"><path id="Z2" title="Aisne" d="M179.025,42.325l-6.3,0.4l-0.2,1.8l-1.9,4.1l1.1,3.5l0.2,5.1l-0.3,2.2l1.1,0.9l-1.3,0.6l-1.2,2.8l-1.3,0.8    l1.4,2.3l-1.5-0.1l0.4,1.5l1.2-0.8l1.4,0.6l0.3,1.4l-1.1,0.8l1.3,0.4l0.9,1.2l-0.3,1.4l1.9,2.1l4.7,3l3.8-5.1l-1.3-0.6l0.5-1.4    l-0.8-1.2l2.7-1.1l-1.6-4l0.6-1.4l4-2l2.7,1l0.4-1.5l-0.1-7.1l1.4-0.1l2.5-3.6l-0.7-1.6l0.7-1.7l-0.4-2.9h-0.2l-1.8-0.6v-0.1    l-7.8-2.1l-2.6,0.9l-1.2-0.9L179.025,42.325z " fill="#094353" stroke="#EEEEEE" stroke-width="0.9"></path> </a>
```

While testing the regex pattern its working fine and matches the links but while applying in code it returning empty list.

```
import scrapy

class scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"
    start_urls = ["https://www.pros-locations-de-voitures.fr/"]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'Links' : response.selector.re('(?<=xlink:href=").*?(?=")')
        }
```

Comment: How did you test the regex to see it is working? Also, why regex if you can use, e.g. xpath?

Comment: I applied the page source and pattern in regexr.com and it highlighted all the links, about selectors, everytime it iterate till the end of source even after trying specific tag and attribute and also there's xlink:href instead of href. I tried several ways, errors kept showing up.

Comment: The `svg` data is loaded by javascript so the data you are looking for is not in the html that is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are looking for is loaded via javascript so to gain access to the data you will have to pre-render the page using either `scrapy-splash`, `selenium` or `scrapy-playwright`. You can then use below xpath selector to obtain the urls. No need to use regex in this case

```py
response.xpath("//*/@*[name()='xlink:href']").getall()
```